# Пути в modx revolution

Tags: modx

Очень нуждаюсь в помощи. Я сделал кнопку фиксированную на сайте. Сайт стоит на `modx revolution` в пути. Там где, ссылка у меня написал `href="/ask"`. У сайта есть 4 поддомена. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на меня перекидывало на---->
`поддомен.домен/ask.html`
Меня перекидывает по адресу, но пишет ошибку 404. То есть такой страницы нет. В исходном коде пишется вот так: `href="/ask"`

Помогите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Очень надо быстро. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

если это у вас документ на сайте то обращайтесть к нему через его номер [[~номер]]. И если у вас в контексте все настроено правильно то вы увидите что ссылка на сайте будет стоять правильной. Вот это надо настроить в каждом контексте: site_start — меняем на ID главной для контекста
base_url — установить это на "/" (без кавычек) т.к. это становится root директорией.
http_host — пишем полностью домен для контекста «blog.site.com»
site_url — сюда соответсвенно «blog.site.com/» последний слэш обязательно,адрес строится по схеме (scheme+http_host+base_url).

Comment: если версия 2.2.7. то там баг, он добавлен в багтрекер. 
Прописывать ссылки пока так: [[~12? &context=`web`]]